# Subview Event handling in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, events, uitableview, touch

I need to create a tableView with customized UITableViewCell that has three  small buttons in their view. Is there any way by which I can trap the click events of Buttons
as well as didSelectRow of TableView and decide what to do?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect those buttons to appropriate IBAction outlets in your controller.
as a sender you will receive the actual custom Cell you were using.

Comment: Thank you Reflog. I am doing it programmatically and it worked.